# Parse SaveInBackgroundWithBlock takes a lot of time

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I have a parse class(named "Story") with following columns:

```
contents - Array of Pointers to Media class
creator - User pointer
lastPosted - Date
title - String
users - array of pointers to User class
```

I am trying to update a PFObject from "Story" class like this

```
storyObject.addUniqueObjectsFromArray(selectedFriends, forKey: "users")
storyObject.setObject(createStoryTextField.text, forKey: "title")
storyObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeed: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    hud.hide(true)
})
```

In some cases the completion block takes a lot of time to complete. By debugging, I have found that the more objects in the "contents" column, the longer it takes. But I haven't even updated the "contents". All the values in the code are not nil. I checked for that too. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please quantify: how much time is a lot, how many objects in the contents column is a lot, etc.

Comment: For 3 items in contents, it takes two minutes, for 10 items in contents, it takes 5 minutes roughly. If contents is nil, it takes 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This is potentially expected behavior. In general when you put something on a background thread (like `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` is almost definitely doing) it will take a lot longer to complete than if you call it on the main thread. If you need it to return quickly and don't mind blocking the UI, you can use the `save:` method.

You also may want to check to see how many requests you are making simultaneously as this may slow down each one.

Finally, if you want to customize the network behavior of Parse more than you already do, you can just use the [REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/) and make all your own network calls (using NSURLSession or a third party library like AFNetworking.)